# PyCryptodome when verifying - AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'n'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to verify a signed message, but I keep getting the error;

> AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'n'

I can't really figure out what causes this error

First of all, I sign the AES encrypted data and then base64 encode it.
Then a json.dump that is printed out, when running the script I pipe it to a file

```
def get_signature(message):
    h = SHA256.new(message)
    signature = pkcs1_15.new(priv_keyObj).sign(h)
    return signature

ENCODING = 'utf-8'

print(json.dumps({
    'EncryptedString':      base64.standard_b64encode(encrypted_data).decode(ENCODING),
    'SignedDataString':     base64.standard_b64encode(get_signature(encrypted_data)).decode(ENCODING),
}))
```

I start by reading the file as json, then when I verity, I read the base64 encoded msg and start with a b64 decoding;

```
def verify_signature(message, signature):
    h = SHA256.new(message)
    try:
        pkcs1_15.new(pub_key_new).verify(h, signature)
        print("The signature is valid.")
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print("The signature is not valid.")

verify_signature(base64.standard_b64decode(data['EncryptedString']), base64.standard_b64decode(data['SignedDataString']))
```

I have tried to make this question minimal and understandable - so please tell me if I need to provide more information.

The full traceback is;

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):

>  File "C:/PATH/Scipts/crypto/decrypt.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(default_decrypt(read_json_file(filename)).decode("utf-8"))

>  File "C:\PATH\Scipts\crypto\crypt_helper_new.py", line 127, in default_decrypt
    verify_signature(base64.standard_b64decode(data['EncryptedString']),
 base64.standard_b64decode(data['SignedDataString']))
encoded msg:  <class 'str'>

>  File "C:\PATH\Scipts\crypto\crypt_helper_new.py", line 65, in verify_signature
    pkcs1_15.new(pub_key_new).verify(h, signature)
message:  b'S\xacU\x14\xb2E\xec\x08\xc3\x83\x18\x8ey\x98\x069'

>  File "C:\PATH\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Signature\pkcs1_15.py", line 106, in verify
    modBits = Crypto.Util.number.size(self._key.n)

> AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a buffer directly to that function. You should read the bytes from the file to create a key object:

```
pub_key_new = RSA.import_key(open('foo.pub').read())
```

The type of `self._key` (i.e. `pub_key_new`) should be:

```
<class 'Crypto.PublicKey.RSA.RsaKey'>
```

Comment: I read the key like this; pub_key_new  = open(pub_key, 'rb') ... Where pub_key is the path. pub_keyObj  = RSA.importKey(pub_key_new.read())

Comment: Ohh, you made me look the right place, when doing the verify, I just the read bytes from pub key, but not the keyObj